# An error occurred while executing an action

Tags: magnolia

I've been trying to follow the guide at [magnolia tutorial](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS57/Part+II+-+Creating+a+light+module).
At the beginning of part II, while trying to create a page of type bucket-list, I get the following error:

```
2018-07-23 11:47:02,192 ERROR nolia.ui.dialog.formdialog.FormDialogPresenterImpl: An error occurred while executing an action.
info.magnolia.ui.api.action.ActionExecutionException: Action execution failed for action: commit
        at info.magnolia.ui.api.action.AbstractActionExecutor.execute(AbstractActionExecutor.java:64) ~[magnolia-ui-api-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.ui.dialog.BaseDialogPresenter.executeAction(BaseDialogPresenter.java:211) [magnolia-ui-dialog-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.ui.dialog.BaseDialogPresenter.onActionFired(BaseDialogPresenter.java:201) [magnolia-ui-dialog-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.ui.dialog.actionarea.renderer.DefaultEditorActionRenderer$DefaultActionView$1.buttonClick(DefaultEditorActionRenderer.java:75) [magnolia-ui-dialog-5.7.jar:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:499) [vaadin-server-8.4.2.jar:8.4.2]
        at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:273) [vaadin-server-8.4.2.jar:8.4.2]
        at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:237) [vaadin-server-8.4.2.jar:8.4.2]
        at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1014) [vaadin-server-8.4.2.jar:8.4.2]
        at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:384) [vaadin-server-8.4.2.jar:8.4.2]
        at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:57) [vaadin-server-8.4.2.jar:8.4.2]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:155) [vaadin-server-8.4.2.jar:8.4.2]
        at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:116) [vaadin-server-8.4.2.jar:8.4.2]
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocation(ServerRpcHandler.java:445) [vaadin-server-8.4.2.jar:8.4.2]
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:410) [vaadin-server-8.4.2.jar:8.4.2]
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:274) [vaadin-server-8.4.2.jar:8.4.2]
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:90) [vaadin-server-8.4.2.jar:8.4.2]
        at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40) [vaadin-server-8.4.2.jar:8.4.2]
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1601) [vaadin-server-8.4.2.jar:8.4.2]
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:445) [vaadin-server-8.4.2.jar:8.4.2]
        at info.magnolia.ui.admincentral.AdmincentralVaadinServlet.service(AdmincentralVaadinServlet.java:141) [magnolia-ui-admincentral-5.7.jar:?]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [servlet-api.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.ServletDispatchingFilter.doFilter(ServletDispatchingFilter.java:148) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:65) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.virtualuri.VirtualUriFilter.doFilter(VirtualUriFilter.java:98) [magnolia-virtual-uri-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.module.cache.executor.Bypass.processCacheRequest(Bypass.java:58) [magnolia-cache-core-5.6.1.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.module.cache.executor.CompositeExecutor.processCacheRequest(CompositeExecutor.java:67) [magnolia-cache-core-5.6.1.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.module.cache.filter.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:220) [magnolia-cache-core-5.6.1.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.i18n.I18nContentSupportFilter.doFilter(I18nContentSupportFilter.java:89) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.RangeSupportFilter.doFilter(RangeSupportFilter.java:77) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.security.BaseSecurityFilter.doFilter(BaseSecurityFilter.java:57) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.security.SecurityCallbackFilter.doFilter(SecurityCallbackFilter.java:84) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.security.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:94) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.module.site.filters.SiteMergeFilter.doFilter(SiteMergeFilter.java:119) [magnolia-site-1.2.2.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MultiChannelFilter.doFilter(MultiChannelFilter.java:83) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.module.cache.filter.GZipFilter.doFilter(GZipFilter.java:73) [magnolia-cache-core-5.6.1.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.security.auth.login.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:127) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.ContentTypeFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeFilter.java:155) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:128) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:65) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.SafeDestroyMgnlFilterWrapper.doFilter(SafeDestroyMgnlFilterWrapper.java:107) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterDispatcher.doDispatch(MgnlFilterDispatcher.java:67) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter.doFilter(MgnlMainFilter.java:110) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter.doFilter(MgnlMainFilter.java:96) [magnolia-core-5.7.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494) [catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651) [catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [catalina.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:412) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1385) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.8]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.8]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_172]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_172]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.8]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_172]
Caused by: info.magnolia.config.registry.Registry$NoSuchDefinitionException: undefined
        at info.magnolia.config.registry.AbstractRegistry.getProvider(AbstractRegistry.java:136) ~[magnolia-configuration-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.ui.dialog.formdialog.FormDialogPresenterFactoryImpl.createFormDialogPresenter(FormDialogPresenterFactoryImpl.java:67) ~[magnolia-ui-dialog-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.pages.app.action.CreatePageAction.execute(CreatePageAction.java:95) ~[magnolia-pages-app-5.7.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.ui.api.action.AbstractActionExecutor.execute(AbstractActionExecutor.java:62) ~[magnolia-ui-api-5.7.jar:?]
        ... 108 more
```

I'm not quite sure what I did wrong, and the error message isn't giving me much to go on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Dodo

Answer (score 0):

Whatever action was supposed to be the commit action of your dialog (the action behind "save" button), is undefined. It's most likely either spelling mistake when naming the action or when referring to it from dialog.
Or for some reason (other error in the log somewhere higher up perhaps) action could not be created from the definition.